# How to create dataset with API data output

Tags: python, json, api, dataframe, error-handling

I am new the Python, and trying to create datasets with data gathered from web. I need help with appending data into new data set. Below is my code.

```
    from pandas import DataFrame
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import requests
    import json
    from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
    import time
    import datetime as dt
    url = "http://test:8999/manage/mgmtrestservice/instanceinfometric? 
 instanceName=TEST_80&agentHostName=TEST.local"`
    payload  = {}
    headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Basic amRlX2FkbW'
    }
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
    print(response.status_code)
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    df = DataFrame(data)
    json.dumps(data)
    for i in range(0,len(df['instanceInformation'])):
        print(df['instanceInformation'][i])
    df = DataFrame.append(data, True)
    df ['time_update'] = dt.datetime.now()
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    stats_web1 = DataFrame.append(df, ignore_index=False, verify_integrity=False, sort=False)
```

I have added an image for reference, need to create a dataset with instancename, information and time with appending data.

Any recommendation for optimizing code would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: BTW: `data = response.json()`

Comment: [pandas.read_json()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) - in your code probably `pandas.read_json(response)`

Comment: So what are your actual outputs of the `print` and `dump` statements and what is your expected output?

Comment: @seven 31415 : I want to store output from the image in new data frame with appending order. Everytime this script runs it should store above output without removing old values.